# Function inside of Redux middleware not working

Tags: reactjs, redux, middleware, redux-thunk

I'm trying to make some middleware which refreshes my JWT if it's expired. I currently have this middleware:

```
import { isTokenExpired, refreshToken } from '../modules/auth/auth.service'
export const jwt = store => next => action => {
    if (typeof action === 'function') {
      console.log("Middleware triggered:", action);
      var theState = store.getState();
      if (theState.auth && theState.auth.authToken && isTokenExpired(theState.auth.authToken)) {
        console.log('This is logging')
        //this function is not being called
        refreshToken(theState.auth.refreshToken);
      }
    }
    return next(action)
}
```

I wish to call the refreshToken() function which will start the process, but so far even the console.log() inside the refreshToken is not calling:

```
export const refreshToken = (refreshToken) => dispatch => {
  console.log('Not logging')
}
```

Also, inside the refreshToken function will be asynchronous while it refreshes the token. I was thinking of setting a "REFRESH_TOKEN_PENDING" type in the reducer, and once the response is received send "REFRESH_TOKEN_SUCCESS" to the reducer. Will this be possible with the middleware?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to **dispatch** `refreshToken()`. If you do have access to `dispatch()` into `jwt` function you should call it like `dispatch(refreshToken())`.

Considering that I'm not sure how you are triggering the `jwt` action, I think this is a valid solution of how you can easily trigger middleware functions inside actions:

```
// ================
//  Container file
// ================
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
// ... other 

function mapActionsToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({
    jwt: path_to_actions_file.jwt
}, dispatch)}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  // ... your state properties
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(YourComponent); // <== YourComponent has to be a React Component

// ==============
//  Actions file
// ==============
export const setConvertTypeActive = store => dispatch => {
  console.log('This is logging.');
  dispatch(refreshToken("md5Token"));
}

export const refreshToken = refreshToken => dispatch => {
  console.log('Should log now.');
}
```

And regarding your last question, yeah, you can create middlewares similar to `refreshToken` action for setting some statuses on reducer. Check the code below:

```
// ============== 
//  Actions file
// ==============
export const refreshToken= {
  pending: () => ({
    // "REFRESH_TOKEN_PENDING"
  }),
  success: (data) => ({
    // "REFRESH_TOKEN_SUCCESS"
  })  
};
```